# How to Read a webpage and extract certain links using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Its on the same domain.. both my Jquery code and the url to read.

What i want to do is first read the webpage using Jquery and then parse certain links which has "ProductDetails.php" and extract "ProductCode" from the webpage into array.

The html page may have many instances of a href="ProductDetails.php which looks like below.

```
<a href="ProductDetails.php?ProductCode=SMS%2D15%2DXLG%2DA7&CartID=1" class="carttext colors_productname cart-item-name">item 1 <a>

<a href="ProductDetails.php?ProductCode=SMS%dfdfde&CartID=2" class="carttext colors_productname cart-item-name">test me item <a>
```

I dont know if this is really possible

Answer (score 2):

You would have to do something like this:

```
var filteredAnchors = $( document.body ).find( 'a' ).map(function( _, anchor ) {
   if( anchor.getAttribute('href').indexOf( 'ProductDetails.php' ) === 0 ) {
       return anchor.getAttribute('href').match( /ProductCode=(.*?)&/ )[ 1 ];
   }
}).get();
```

`filteredAnchors` now should contain all product codes.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WgwSr/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you started:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "pagetoload.html",
    success: function(htmlofthepage) {
        var html = $(htmlofthepage),
            resultarray = []; // the array containing our final result set

        // getting all of the anchor tags we want to look at
        $('a[href^="ProductDetails.php"]', html).each(function () {
            var t = $(this), // the anchor tag
                href = t.prop('href'), // the href of the tag (eg. ProductDetails.php?...)
                start = href.indexOf('ProductCode', 0),
                begin = 0,
                end = 0;

            if (start > -1) {
                begin = href.indexOf('=', start) + 1;
                end = href.indexOf('&', begin);
                resultarray.push(href.split(begin, end));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuerys `each`function:

```
   jQuery(function($){
     var links = [];
     $("a[href^=ProductDetails.php]").each(function(){
        links.push(this.href.replace(/^.*\?/,'');
     });
   });
```